# Hide DockableControlPanes in DockAreaPane

Tags: infragistics, dockable-windows

I'm working with Infragistics controls. I have an UserControl that is put into a DockableControlPane, that is then put into a DockAreaPane that is inside of an UltraDockManager, that is inside a Form. 
Example udockManager.DockAreas has 5 DockAreaPane(dap1,dap2,dap3,dap4,dap5) and dap1 has 3 DockableControlPanes in its Panes (P1, P2, P3).
I want to hide  P2 based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide it at all, e.g. not visible by the user, call Close method over the pane like this:

```
P2.Close();
```

If at latter moment you need to show it again call Show method like this:

```
P2.Show();
```